# I got this error PHP Parse error Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

When I write any command like php artisan or composer update i got this `'?' in .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line use the `??` operator  which is a php  7.0 feature.

Make sure to use PHP 7.0 or above

Comment: thank you for your answer. how to remove the version of the php. do you know?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: debian with hosting plesk.

Comment: Look at this https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/plesk-now-supports-php-7-1-x/